# Error reporting for Web Services: In the service or the caller?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, exception

We have built a web-service which as part of the validations, throws a number of errror messages to the calling application. The web-services which we built doesn't do any error handling\reporting and only returns the error message (the details would be available in the logs of course).

We have come into issues where we are rejecting the input xmls with an error message, and the calling application is expecting us to report the errors as and when they occur. My question here is whose responsibility is it to report the errors? Until now I was thinking the calling platform should be reporting if their xmls gets rejected? Am I wrong in thinking so?

If so, should I be writing all the rejections into my tables? This web-service along with others receive a huge number of requests daily.

Please note that these are valid business errors thrown by the web-service, or errors due to incorrect xml's received

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SOAP standard, you can use and implement your own custom fault bean in service side using @Fault annotation. Whereas, it seems you are using Rest API, so it would be better to use @ExceptionHandler for these like as:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring-3-2.html

Comment: My question is not how to do it, but the system which handles it.. the caller or the service?

Comment: Error reporting for web service is usually on the service. But you need to have make the usage of the error message with certain condition on the caller side.